# Health checks in blocking (synchronous) web-frameworks

Tags: kubernetes, uwsgi, synchronous, web-frameworks

I have blocking (synchronous) web-framework with uWSGI. Task if to prepare /health endpoint for kubernetes to ensure that pod is alive. There is no issue with endpoint itself, but issue is in sync nature. For example, if I define 8 processes in uWSGI and web-application processes 8 heavy requests, call to /health will be queued and depends on timeouts, kubernetes may not receive response in some period of time and decides to kill/restart pod. Of course I can run another web-service on different port but it will require changes in code and increase complexity of deployment. Maybe I'm missing something and it's possible to define exclusive worker in uWSGI to process /health endpoint in non-blocking way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: After reading your question it seems like uWSGI can't handle more that 1 request at one moment, is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, no, it's not due to uWSGI but due to sync nature of web-framework behind it.

Comment: blocking/sync nature doesn't mean that multiple calls can't be processed in parallel. If your healthprobes dont perform any heavy operations and return quickly then you should not worry much about it.

Answer (score 0):

WSGI is an inherently synchronous protocol. There has been some work to create a new async-friendly replacement called ASGI, but it's only implemented by the Django Channels project AFAIK. While you can mount a sync-mode WSGI app in an async server (generally using threads), you can't go the other way. So you could, for example, write some `twisted.web` code that grabs requests to `/health` and handles them natively via Twisted and hands off everything else to the WSGI container. I don't know of anything off the shelf for this though.

Comment: Also, do you work for my company? :P Because we just had a prod outage due to this last week. It was not fun.